# how can i add auto suggestion to my php mysql search engine?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to create a php mysql search engine working like an e-comerce search engine with auto suggestion using ajax?... my table is like

```
id    cat    name 

 1    men    subi
 2    men    flick
 3    women  sheeba
 4    women  leena
```

my form is like

```
<html>
<head>
<title>search engine</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = 'ss.php' method ='GET'>
<input type = "text"  name = "q">
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "search"
</body>
</html>
```

and my ss.php is

```
$k = $_GET["q"];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($con,"x");
$terms=explode(" ",$k);
$i=0;
$set_limit = ("9");
$subi = "";
foreach ($terms as $each) 

{
$i++;
$escapedSearchString = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$each);
if ($i == 1 )
    $subi.= " title LIKE '%$escapedSearchString%' ";
else
    $subi.= " AND title LIKE '%$escapedSearchString%' ";

} 
$query = "select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from table WHERE $subi order by       rand() limit $set_limit";

$qry = mysqli_query($con,"$query");

$row_object = mysqli_query($con,"Select Found_Rows() as rowcount");
$row_object = mysqli_fetch_object($row_object);
$actual_row_count = $row_object->rowcount;
$result = $actual_row_count;
```

it's work fine when i search a words like subi or sheeba bt what i want is if i'm start to type a word 's' it 'll shows auto suggestion like

```
sheeba
subi
sheeba in women
subi in men
```

if the user clicks sheeba the query will automaticaly changed to like this

```
" select * from table where title like '%sheeba%' "
```

and if the user clicks the 'sheeba in women' the 'll query changed to like this

```
" select * from table where cat = 'women' and title like '%sheeba%' "
```

How Can i obtain this?
pls answer briefly...
tnx in advance....

Comment: Use `ajax` for this and display the suggestion from the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create custom code rather than using a plugin then you need something like this

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name='q']").on("keyup",function(event){
            search_value = $(this).val();
            // check whether the input is not empty or has characters
            if(value.length > 0){
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/path/to/file',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: "q="+search_value,
                    success: function(response){
                        // create suitable html body to show your reponse 
                        $("suggestion_box_id").html("your/created/htmlcontent");
                    }
                })

            }
            else {
                $("suggestion_box_id").html("");
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: pls provide the answer with very simple examble sir, like how can i change my form script and search script? where to use your ajax codings. i can't understand what you are trying to say me...

Answer (score 0):

Take a reference from [here:](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) which is best example of php with ajax and auto suggestion

It works fine for me always.